# Sort an array of arrays based on values from another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array which i would like to sort it based on values from another one.
FIrst array:

```
$array1 = ( [0]=> Int(2) 
    [1]=>Array(['id']=>String(5) , ['value']=>String(10))
    [2]=>Array(['id']=>String(5) , ['value']=>String(10))
    [3]=>Array(['id']=>String(5) , ['value']=>String(10))
)
```

And second one:

```
 $array2 = (1,4,3)
```

The result should be based on $array2:

```
 $array1 = ( [0]=> Int(2) 
    [1]=>Array(['id']=>String(5) , ['value']=>String(10))
    [3]=>Array(['id']=>String(5) , ['value']=>String(10))
    [2]=>Array(['id']=>String(5) , ['value']=>String(10))
)
```

I've tried a bubble sort but does not work:

```
  for ($i = 1 ; $i <= $array1[0] ; $i++){
    for ($j = $i+1 ; $j <= $array1[0] ; $j++){
        if ($array2[$i] < $array2[$j]){
            $temp = $array1[$i];
            $array1[$i] = $array1[$j];
            $array1[$j] = $temp;  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did the `4` come from in `$array2`?

Comment: I think you need to explain yourself a little better. What do you mean that the result should be based on array 2? What exactly are you looking to do? In your bubble sort you're sorting by strings, comparing which one is alphabetically before the other and just using the Int in the position 0 of the array. What is that Int? The amount of entries in the array or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried checking array_multisort? You could inject array 2 into array 1 and then sort it that way?

Comment: could you be more specific ? what do you mean by inject ? show me an example.